# Changing defined function fragment into testable function, how to pass argument?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to refactor some code, to make it testable. A large part of it uses #define to fill in repetitive code in functions. I am trying to change it in actual functions, but I ran into a stumbling block.

Note: the original code is from [dithering algorithm](http://en.literateprograms.org/Floyd-Steinberg_dithering_(C))

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char R, G, B;
} RGBTriple;

#define compute_disperse(channel) \
error = ((int)(currentPixel->channel)) - palette.table[index].channel; \
image.pixels[(x+1) + (y+0)*image.width].channel += (error*7) >> 4; \
image.pixels[(x-1) + (y+1)*image.width].channel += (error*3) >> 4; \
image.pixels[(x+0) + (y+1)*image.width].channel += (error*5) >> 4; \
image.pixels[(x+1) + (y+1)*image.width].channel += (error*1) >> 4;
```

inside the actual method

```
RGBTriple* currentPixel = &(image.pixels[x + y*image.width]);
compute_disperse(R);
compute_disperse(G);
compute_disperse(B);
```

If I try to convert the compute_disperse into an actual function, then **I need to pass the 'channel" somehow as values of R, G, or B.**

I have tried to pass it as an unsigned char but I get the error

```
error: 'struct RGBTriple' has no member named 'channel'
```

I read on defining R G and B but can't make it work... How can I convert the given section into an actual function, instead of a macro ?

Comment: +1 for trying to throw away that horrible and useless macro and writing a proper function instead

Comment: Besides the channel the macro refers to global or function/class variables. How do you handle these?

Comment: @Manu343726  There is no "type with the channel member"   He's passing the name of a structure member to the macro (i.e. R refers to RGBTriple.R etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a follow-up to Slava's answer, you *can* use member pointers... as template arguments !

```
template <unsigned char RGBTriple::*Tchannel>
compute_disperse(/* Whatever you need */) {
    error = ((int)(currentPixel->*Tchannel)) - palette.table[index].*Tchannel;
    /* ... */
}
```

Least typing possible, flexible, and fully inlined by any decent compiler.

Comment: How do I define Tchannel ?

Comment: @Thalia `compute_disperse<&RGBTriple::R>(/* whatever you need */)`

Answer (score 2):

Obvious solution would be to pass pointer to member `unsigned char RGBTriple::*channel` but I bet that would have perfomance issues. I would use template instead:

```
enum ChannelName { R, G, B };

template <ChannelName>
unsigned char &getChannel( RGBTriple &rgb );

template <>
unsigned char &getChannel<R>( RGBTriple &rgb ) { return rgb.R; }

template <>
unsigned char &getChannel<G>( RGBTriple &rgb ) { return rgb.G; }

template <>
unsigned char &getChannel<B>( RGBTriple &rgb ) { return rgb.B; }
```

then

```
template <ChannelName ch>
compute_disperse( /* parameters, probably currentPixel, pallette and image */ ) {
    error = ((int)getChannel<ch>( *currentPixel ) - getChannel<ch>( palette.table[index] );
    getChannel<ch>( image.pixels[(x+1) + (y+0)*image.width] ) += (error*7) >> 4;
    ...
}
```

then you will call `compute_disperse` this way:

```
compute_disperse<R>( /* parameters */  );
compute_disperse<G>( /* parameters */  );
compute_disperse<B>( /* parameters */  );
```

What parameters you need to provide to the function is out of scope of this answer, you need to analyze which data this function access.

Comment: Nothing stops you from making these parameters `const&` :)

Comment: @Quentin actually macro `compute_disperse` modifies some channels so lvalue reference is required, he may provide const and not const variants though.

Comment: What do I put in the argument list for the channel ? or... what do I put for the empty template<> ? I have never sen them written like that

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out - it is an easier to understand solution, I will try Quentin's version too :-)

Comment: @Thalia I believe both versions would have similar perfomance, so you should use variant that is more readable for you. Quentin's variant is less verbose, I would prefer it.

Comment: Both versions are great and I love that I learnt a few new things, once I understand I prefer the more compact version, but I thank you so much for yours too

Answer (score 1):

Use an union for your RGB type, allowing refer to channels both as `R`,`G`,`B` and as an array. Then write an enum with the channels (Actually used as indices of the array):

```
struct RGB
{
    union 
    {
        struct { unsigned char R , G , B };
        unsigned char channels[3];
    };
};

enum rgb_channel{ R = 0 , G = 1 , B = 2 };
```

Here is an example:

```
unsigned char get_channel_value( RBG color , rgb_channel channel )
{
    return color.channels[(int)channel]; //The cast is not strictly necessary, but
                                         //makes the code more concise.
}

//You could do this:
color.R = 0;

//Or this:
color.channels[R] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is unchanged:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned char R, G, B;
} RGBTriple;
```

Typedef an accessor function:

```
typedef char & Accessor(RGBTriple *);
```

Define accessor functions for each channel

```
char & AccessR(RGBTriple * pixel) { return pixel->R;}
char & AccessG(RGBTriple * pixel) { return pixel->G;}
char & AccessB(RGBTriple * pixel) { return pixel->B;}
```

Here's your new compute_disperse function (not a macro any more)

```
void compute_disperse(RGBTriple * currentPixel, Accessor access)
{
    int error = ((int)access(currentPixel) - access(palette.table[index]);
    access(image.pixels[(x+1) + (y+0)*image.width]) += (error*7) >> 4;
    access(image.pixels[(x-1) + (y+1)*image.width]) += (error*3) >> 4;
    access(image.pixels[(x+0) + (y+1)*image.width]) += (error*5) >> 4;
    access(image.pixels[(x+1) + (y+1)*image.width]) += (error*1) >> 4;
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```
RGBTriple* currentPixel = &(image.pixels[x + y*image.width]);
compute_disperse(currentPixel, AccessR);
compute_disperse(currentPixel, AccessG);
compute_disperse(currentPixel, AccessB);
```

Aside: I would switch to using references rather than pointers, but I tried to stay as close as possible to the original approach.

Comment: +1. Why passing the function by reference? Thats not necessary nor useful